# Rewrite parts of SEO friendly URL in Nginx

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting, seo

i have a URL like this Example

```
http://www.example.com/city/new-york/company-name
```

and

```
http://www.example.com/contact/new-york/company-name
```

Is it possible to make my URLs to this URLs?

```
http://www.example.com/new-york/company-name
```

and

```
http://www.example.com/new-york/company-name/contact
```

My real URLs are

```
http://www.example.com/city.php?city=new-york&amp;company=company-name
```

and

```
http://www.example.com/contact.php?city=new-york&amp;company=company-name
```

Comment: It is possible, what have you tried?

Comment: I do not know, I try to find out whether it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try these rules,

```
rewrite ^contact/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)$ contact.php?city=$1&amp;company=$2;

rewrite ^city/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)$ city.php?city=$1&amp;company=$2;
```

in your `location /` directive.